# Eclipse xslt plugin

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xslt

Hi I'm facing an issue with Eclipse XSL plugin , I'm using extensions feature on my xsl to generate xml as output. But i'm facing the below error:

```
17:55:38,998 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
17:55:39,001 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=C:\allinone\JRepo\Java\newwork\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\endorsed
17:55:39,006 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: C:\allinone\JRepo\Java\newwork\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\launch\launch.xml
17:55:39,506 INFO  [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Transforming...
(Location of error unknown)javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Instance method call to method getFruitType requires an Object instance as first argument
17:55:39,528 INFO  [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Done.
```

XSL file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Access packaged method in a class file, assigning the classpath to the prefix.-->

<xsl:stylesheet 
version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:pf="com.altova.extfunc.PackagedfruitStatic">

<xsl:output indent="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="fn pf xsl fo xs"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="myLemon" select="'yellow'" /> 

<test>
<staticMethod><xsl:value-of select="pf:getFruitType()"/></staticMethod>
</test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java class file :

```java
package com.altova.extfunc;

public class PackagedfruitStatic {
    //static variable

    public static String getFruitType()
    {
        return " Static fruit";  
    }
}
```

I Configured Xalan parser in eclipse plugin. BTW I'm using the latest JAVA EE IDE (Helios) from eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is not an Eclipse problem, but more of a classpath and XSLT issue.

1. Make sure that the class file (PackagedfruitStatic.class) is located in `com/altova/extfunc`, and that the base directory containing these subdirectories is in the classpath. (Also note that `com.altova.extfunc` is used for [Altova XSLT extensions](http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlreporting/index.html?xextjava_udefclassfiles.htm). I think you should choose another package name for your Xalan extensions).
2. The `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute is not allowed on `xsl:output`. Put it on the root element (`xsl:stylesheet`)
3. The stylesheet specifies `version="2.0"`, but the Xalan XSLT processor does not support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You are correct it is totally a classpath issue. I added the source files/jar files to the classpath ,  in the place provided for classpath towards that plugin. (Runas--> XSLT --> classpath